# Компиляция итогового exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Нужно сделать готовый отдельный .exeшник из проекта. Вытаскивая из bin/debug получаю ошибку на другом компьютере. Как сделать так, чтобы после компиляции получался единый .exe, который можно было бы запустить на другом компьютере?

Помогите еще вот с чем: как поставить в настройки компилятора это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти

Comment: У вас скриншот от настроек компилятора C++, который к C# не имеет отношения.

Answer (score 1):

На другом компьютере надо установить .NET Framework. Если есть желание запускать его без установки фреймворка - попробуйте запускать его через [`Mono`](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/windows/) (Mono установки не требует).

Comment: т.е., если я хочу запустить программу на компьютере, где не обладаю админ. правами, я не смогу этого сделать?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, Mono установки не требует? что вы имеете ввиду? его нужно точно также ставить, как и Net Framework.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov mono - переносимая программа. Ее можно скопировать на другой компьютер и запустить без установки.